# Newtonsoft JsonSerializer doesn't set correct type

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a custom wrapper for [`JsonSerializer`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) which looks something like this:

```
public class MySerializer
{
    JsonSerializer serializer;

    public MySerializer()
    {
        serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        };
    }

    public byte[] Serialize<T>(T value)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                serializer.Serialize(new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter), value);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public T Deserialize<T>(byte[] serialized)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(serialized))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                return serializer.Deserialize<T>( new JsonTextReader(streamReader));
        }
    }
}
```

It usually works fine and I *really need* to use `JsonSerializer` because of limitations in the project. I'm not looking for any other serializer.

The class I want to serialize/deserialize looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public House LivingArrangement { get; set; } = new TreeHouse();
}

public class House
{
    public int NumberOfBeds { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsInTree => false; // just to show the issue
}

public class TreeHouse : House
{
    public override bool IsInTree => true; // just to show the issue
}
```

In the real world it's much more complex, but this is just to illustrate the issue. Note that every `Person` is living in a `TreeHouse` if nothing else is set. This is very important and cannot be changed due to other limitations in my project. The type must be set to `TreeHouse` when the class is initated. It cannot be `null`.

The problem is that when the class is deserialized the type is `TreeHouse`, even though I explicitly set it to `House`. See the test below.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Serialization_Test()
    {
        var item = new Person();
        item.LivingArrangement = new House(); // This person lives in a house.
        item.LivingArrangement.NumberOfBeds = 2;

        var serializer = new MySerializer();
        var serializedItem = serializer.Serialize(item);

        var deserializedItem = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(serializedItem);
        Console.WriteLine(deserializedItem.LivingArrangement.GetType()); // Output: UnitTestProject1.TreeHouse

        // Works fine!
        Assert.IsTrue(item.LivingArrangement.NumberOfBeds == 2);

        // The assert fails.
        Assert.IsFalse(deserializedItem.LivingArrangement.IsInTree);

        // The assert fails.
        Assert.AreEqual(deserializedItem.LivingArrangement.GetType(), typeof(House));
    }
```

Why does `JsonSerializer` keep `TreeHouse` instead of initiating a new instance of `House`? And how do I fix it, but still using JsonSerializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set an additional property `ObjectCreationHandling`:

```
serializer = new JsonSerializer
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
};
```

Now you have more information in your json.
If you have a `TreeHouse` set as `LivingArrangement` your JSON-String has type information inside (`$type`).